# Image not displaying in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8

I have an image that does not display in IE8, I have deleted the cache and all temp IE files and reload.  This is the code:

```
<img src='/images/site/categories/Display_all_2.jpg'>
```

If I use the direct path to the image IE displays the image fine

```
http://my_domain/images/site/categories/Display_all_2.jpg
```

I have other images on the same page that works fine, no problems in Chrome and Firefox. Initially I thought the image was corrupt but then it should not display using the URL path to the the image.

Any ideas?

/M

Comment: Have you tried ~/images/ note the use of the ~. Would be good to have some context around your folder structure.

Comment: Hi Dr Schizo, I found out the reason. It was because I had height and width as ="" like this: <img src='/images/site/categories/Display_all_2.jpg' height='' width=''>

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason it did not work, my code actually looked like this

```
`<img src="/images/site/categories/Display_all_2.jpg" height="" width="">`
```

The empty height and width mess it up in IE.

/M